# Can I trigger a release after the other release?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I've got a deployment release (A) and E2E test run release (B). I cannot merge them.
Can I somehow set B release run after given stage in A release completes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [VSTS Creare Release](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=venzhyk.vnzk-vsts-tasks) Task extension:

> Creates a new release as part of the current release pipeline.

[image]

So, add it in the last step of deployment release (A).

Comment: Hmm, not sure if I will be even able to use it commercially if its even spelled badly? Are there any alternatives?

Comment: you can do it yourself with PowerShell and rest API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

Comment: Release Orchestrator is awesome.

Answer (score 3):

Agree with Shayki Abramczyk.

I would like to share the Powershell script sample and other extensions.

**Powershell script to trigger the release:**

Here is the powershell script example:

```
$VSTSAccoutName="organiztionname"   
$teamProjectName="projectname"
$personaltoken = " PAT "
$ReleaseMetadata = '{"definitionId":  15  }';
 
$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($personaltoken)"))
$header = @{authorization = "Basic $token"}
$Uri = 'https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/' + $VSTSAccoutName +'/'+ $teamProjectName + '/_apis/release/releases?api-version=5.0'
$ReleaseResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -ContentType application/json -Uri $Uri -Body $ReleaseMetadata -Headers $header
Write-Host $ReleaseResponse
```

You could add the  powershell task in the `Release A -> Target stage`.

**Other extensions:** [Release Orchestrator extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dmitryserbin.release-orchestrator)

[image]

This extension also supports selecting to trigger the stages specified in release B.

Comment: Thank you for your input.
Can I run a release from another AzureDevOps project using powershell?

Comment: Of course. You just need to make sure that the PAT is valid and change some parameters.